# Python 3 - How to convert a string to a list of dictionary

Tags: string, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the data coming as a API which is in a string format
And the data is exactly like list of dictionaries

```
'{'key1':'value','key2':'value','key3':'value'},{'key1':'value','key2':'value','key3':'value'},...'
```

Is their any way I can convert this string to a list of dictionary?

Comment: use `json` module

Comment: Are you sure it is * exactly* like that? Because JSON is commonly used for APIs and it uses double quotes, not single. Paste a real example not a manually typed one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) should do the trick:

```
from ast import literal_eval
result = literal_eval(my_string)
```

Comment: This works like a charm, Can you explain a little more about ast package and litral_eval function?

Comment: The API is unlikely to be sending stringified Python. More likely the `json` module should be used.